# PyQt5 QSqlTableModel Cancel After Row Insert

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

According the Docs for QSQLTableModel, deleting a row from the model does not remove the row from the table view until the transaction(s) are committed.  I can work around that; however, when I insert a new row and then cancel the edit, I need to remove that row from the model AND the view.  Any suggestions on how I can pull this off?

```
class SclDataModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTable("scldata")
        self.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, 'recordid')
        self.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, 'svcdataid')
        self.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, 'Receipts Start')
        self.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, 'Receipts End')
        self.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, 'Billing Rate')
        self.action = 0

    def revert(self):
        if self.action ==1   
            # How TO Remove the inserted row from the view????


class SclDataBrowse(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataBrowse, self).__init__(parent)

    ...

    def add_record(self):
        rec = self.model.record()
        rec.setValue('recordid', str(uuid.uuid4()))
        rec.setValue('svcdataid', self.parentid)
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRecord(row, rec)
        ndx = self.model.index(row, 2)
        self.model.action = 1
        self.tbl_View.edit(ndx)
        self.tbl_View.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(ndx, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
```

Comment: what is your database.

Comment: `db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")`

Comment: The only thing I can think of to do is issue a self.submitAll() in the revert method but that seems a bit sloppy to me.

Comment: Why do you think that? For me it is the right method although I have not tried it.

Comment: Doesn't submitAll() reload the model from the database?

Comment: I have not reviewed it but I do not think it does, try and verify that it does or not.

Comment: Using self.submitAll() actually adds the record in the revert method.  Perhaps the wrong signal to catch?

Comment: If that is the answer, I ask you to publish it as an answer and not as an edition. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by edition?

Comment: If you have found the solution to your problem then you should post it as an answer, but I see that you have edited your question pointing to your solution, instead you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet :-)

Comment: you can answer your own question, what you can not do is mark it as correct, that you can do it in 2 days.

Comment: LOL!  I didn't see the BIG BLUE BUTTON.  Will do

Comment: If you have questions with the same status please also do the same. :-)

Comment: Unlikely.  You always seem to answer my questions :-)

Comment: okay, in 2 days you can mark your own answer as correct. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Changed the revert method to the following:

```
def revert(self):
     if self.action == 1:                
          self.removeRow(self.rowCount()-1)
          self.submitAll()
```